# How to set up an NUnit project - Project Base and Application Base

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

Please forgive a very n00b question, but when using the GUI runner, Project->Edit...

What directories should Project Base and Application Base point to?

(Using the latest NUnit 2.5.7 and a VC# 2008 Express solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click File => Open Project and select your dll that contains your nunit tests. Those directories will be set automatically.

Comment: Yes,that works, but then it only has a 'Default' configuration. What uses do the ProjectBase and AppBase have if you save a NUnit project?

Comment: @Andy: Unfortunately I never used them.

Comment: That's fair enough. Just started using NUnit and I'm trying to get a feel for it. Right now I'm happy to simply point it at the dll and leave it at that.